# Поиск изображений-околодубликатов

Tags: алгоритм, изображения, поиск

Столкнулся с задачей поиска одинаковых изображений. Как и во всём новом, получил избыток смежной, не нужной мне информации, множество английской литературы и прочего.

Итак, мне хотелось бы получить наводку на достаточно качественный и быстрый алгоритм, который, однако, не является из ряда вон сложным. То есть, к абсолютному качеству и большому функционалу не стремлюсь (мне это не нужно), но алгоритм должен соответствовать таким условиям:

- Находит не просто похожие, а идентичные объекты, причём под идентичными подразумевается не почти-копия изображения как такового, а скорее отображение точно такого же предмета (near-duplicates): он может повернуться, наклониться, сдвинуться вбок, стать темнее/ярче, покрыться сторонними деталями и тому подобное, но это с большой вероятностью один и тот же предмет;
- То есть, следует работать не только с низкими частотами, которые, грубо говоря, определяют структуру, ведь тут важны более-менее однозначно характеризующие объект детали, которые теряются, если переходить к низким частотам;
- Алгоритм работает куда меньше секунды, желательно настолько быстро, чтобы успевать сравнивать хотя бы пару десятков изображений с такой же парой десятков, то есть, качественность важна, но скорость - важнее;
- Исходные картинки сами по себе обычно не очень большие, а их количество, думаю, будет сравнительно небольшим, предположительно, в рамках нескольких сотен;
- Исходные картинки - чёрно-белые и безо всякой дополнительной обработки, разве что кроме нормализации; то есть, учитывать, что алгоритм должен уметь искать какие-то хорошенько и по-разному обработанные, но одинаковые по содержанию, изображения, нет необходимости;
- Огромным плюсом будет существование не смутного описания алгоритма, а чего-либо конкретного, в оптимуме - псевдокод, в идеале - код.

Да, прошу направления, какой алгоритм раскапывать, это не требование в духе "сделайте за меня всё", это - "более знающие, пожалуйста, сделайте оптимальную выборку, чтобы я мог нормально сориентироваться, так как я сейчас дезориентирован".

Comment: Про SIFT знаете?

Comment: @gbg, да, но я не очень уверен, насколько это трудоёмко. Хотя рассматривал наряду с другими для возможного досуга, времени на который сейчас, увы, нет. К тому же, по всей видимости, на этой штуке лежит патент.

Comment: В любом случае, всегда стоит знать про несколько разных альтернатив, выполняющих одну и ту же конкретную задачу.

Comment: Вероятно, подходит это, но надо пробовать: https://habrahabr.ru/post/211773/

Comment: у SURF те же интересности с патентом, что и у SIFT

Comment: Я как-то пробовал такое: нужно было дамские сумки распознавать. Куча изображений отличного качества со всех ракурсов. В итоге ничего не заработало ни с SIFT, ни c SURF, ни с ещё несколькими. А всё потому, что во всех этих мануалах и статьях в инете всегда берут изображение и вырезают из него часть и практически никогда не берут иное, снятое спустя время, в других условиях освещения или на другую камеру. Я пробовал использовать особенные точки для трекинга лица (межкадровые изменения минимальны) - работает. Стоит чуть побольше времени добавить и погрешность дикая.

Comment: А что за предметы требуется искать? Приведите хотя бы пару изображений в качестве примера. Возможно это даст основание порекомендовать что-нибудь конкретное. Или имеется в виду вообще что угодно в качестве объекта интереса?

Comment: @alexis031182, ездят автомобили, ходят люди, всё такое. Алгоритм их ищет, пока что вполне базовый и примитивный, затем сохраняет. Хотелось бы не сохранять одни и те же предметы, которые находятся в видеопотоке (нецелесообразно), для этого можно сравнивать новонайденный объект со старым в некоем кэше, и, если объект тот же, заменить старую картинку в кэше на новую, чтобы учесть изменения. Возможно, я не в ту сторону ищу.

Comment: @brenoritvrezorkre , если речь идёт о кеше, который хранит объекты, когда те выходят из кадра на длительное время, а затем снова заходят, то тогда тут нет простого и тем более быстрого решения, т.к. задача сводится к распознаванию не типов объектов, а конкретных объектов, да ещё разных типов. Любые другие методы, будь-то вычисление хэша, точки особенностей, да просто межкадровое сравнение не дадут удовлетворения. Если же речь о кеше при движении объекта в пределах кадра, то - оптический поток.

Comment: @alexis031182, достаточно просто учитывать то, что находимые в видеопотоке объекты - одни и те же, и не нужно их сохранять больше одного раза каждый. Они могут двигаться, могут не двигаться в тот или иной момент времени, главное - это то, что по факту некоторый набор найденных в разных кадрах объектов по факту является одним и тем же автомобилем или одним и тем же человеком. Про оптический поток спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: @brenoritvrezorkre , а ну тогда - да, оптический поток. Алгоритм Лукаса-Канаде, например. Работает очень быстро, в OpenCV имеется его реализация. Даже если объект остановится и не будет двигаться - это не важно, он однозначно идентифицируется, т.к. оптический поток - это не обязательно движение объекта. Тут у Вас будут только две проблемы - зафиксировать момент, когда новый объект появится в кадре (иногда это сложно, если объекты в кадре относительно мелкие), и второй - разделение объектов между собой, если они расположены рядом, как любят делать пешеходы - идти вместе.

Comment: @alexis031182, спасибо, вы ответили на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из комментариев к вопросу стало понятно, что в целом суть задачи сводится к вычислению межкадровой разницы и поиску соответствия локальных изменений отдельных единиц интереса во времени. Проще говоря, если в кадре смещается несколько объектов, то необходимо различать, какое из смещений к каковому объекту относится.

**Детектор движения**

Как только речь заходит о межкадровой разнице, то в качестве решения сразу всплывает детектор движения. В составе фреймворка OpenCV имеется прекрасный пример, демонстрирующий возможности этого инструмента, да и Youtube переполнен соответствующими роликами. В том числе с вычислением вектора движения и связанных компонент, что составляют части целого объекта.

Однако у детектора движения имеются два очевидно слабых момента. Первый заключается в том, что если съёмка ведётся на улице, то фактор изменения фона (облачность в солнечный день или сильный ветер камеру на столбе трясёт) приводит к тому, что относительно малые пиксельные изменения объектов теряются на фоне более глобальных изменений во всём кадре. И это практически никогда не удаётся победить.

Второй момент - это прекращение движения объекта. Полное, либо просто существенное снижение скорости. И если автомобили на скоростной трассе редко стремятся остановиться, то те же самые автомобили на оживлённом перекрёстке будут соблюдать правила дорожного движения. Пешеходы же, так вообще могут следовать одним только им известной логике, нарушая порой даже самые лояльные законы перемещения в пространстве. Получасовое преодоление бордюра на карачках - это одна из самых безобидных картин, которую будет вынужден понять и принять цифровой разум алгоритма.

Исходя из обозначенных моментов, можно сделать вывод, что детектор движения - это вполне себе подходящее решение, но только лишь при наличии одного условия: скорость смещения объектов интереса должна быть всегда существенно выше, нежели чем скорость изменения фона. Если это правило не соблюдается, то функционал детектора движения необходимо дополнить обработчиками исключительных ситуаций, в которых объект интереса может начать терять в скорости, либо полностью остановиться.

Таким обработчиком исключительной ситуации может являться использование так называемых особенных точек (feature points) на той части изображения, которая содержит медленно изменяемый объект. Как только детектор движения начнёт фиксировать резкое уменьшение количества пикселей (значение подбирается эмпирически), изменившихся между двумя кадрами, то в дело вступают особенные точки, которые и будут следить за местоположением объекта до начала возобновления фазы его активного движения.

Особенные точки изображения в противовес детектору движения в целом неинвариантны к быстрому изменению объекта в естественной среде, но в то же время позволяют относительно легко его обнаруживать от кадра к кадру, если тот не претерпевает существенных изменений.

**Оптический поток**

Вычисление оптического потока является альтернативой вышеуказанному подходу. В какой-то мере это решение - компромисс использованию особенных точек и детектора движения.

С одной стороны, вычисление оптического потока становится чрезвычайно затруднительно, если объект интереса смещается очень быстро при некоей стандартной скорости кадрового захвата, но в то же самое время неплохо себя чувствует на средних и малых скоростях движения. В случае же полной неподвижности объекта может проявиться погрешность в детекции его местоположения. Эти нюансы индивидуальны для каждого алгоритма вычисления оптического потока.

Например алгоритм Лукаса-Канаде, производящий вычисление сдвига объекта по предварительно отобранным точкам, может запросто потерять этот самый объект просто по той причине, что у того большое количество пикселей в некоторой позиции и её окрестностях имеют близкое значение. Это вполне себе может произойти, если рассматривать в качестве объекта интереса автомобиль, крыша, двери и прочие части которого имеют близкие по цвету области и не выражены какими-либо особенностями. Но в связи с тем, что точек для сравнения число ограниченное (значительно меньше, нежели чем пикселей в интересующей области), то сам процесс поиска производится на высокой скорости с минимальными затратами вычислительных ресурсов.

В противовес - алгоритм Фарнебека, производящий вычисление оптического потока для всех пикселей заданной области изображения. С ним обычно наблюдается более точный результат, но и существенное потребление вычислительных ресурсов.

**Вместо заключения**

В ответе неспроста упоминается детектор движения как часть некоего комплексного решения. Несмотря на его ограничения, в целом он имеет одно значительное преимущество, которое зачастую становится принципиальным в отдельных задачах - детектор движения позволяет определять границы объектов. Ни оптический поток, ни особенные точки таковой информации не дают, а значит разделение рядом расположенных объектов будет весьма затруднительно.